# Jquery Radio and text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my Jsp I have two radio buttons rb1 and rb2 and two text boxes txt1 and txt2...

How can I disable my text box txt2 whenever rb2 was checked?

Here is my code:

```
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1""></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt2"></asp:TextBox>

       <asp:RadioButton ID="rb1" Text="hello" runat="server" />

       <asp:RadioButton ID="rb2" Text="world" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.change` events from jQuery:

```
$("#<%= rb2.ClientID %>").change(function() {
    $("#<%= txt2.ClientID %>").prop("disabled", this.checked);
});
```

Comment: If you aren't fond of the ASP.NET requirement to resolve the element Id, you can change that in the configuration of the project.  `system.web --> pages clientIDMode="Static"`.  Will cause .Net to not generate the Id for you, but use what you assigned to the control.

Answer (score 2):

Bind it to the **change event**

```
$('[id*=rb2]').on('change', function() {
    var txt = $('[id*=txt2]');

    txt.prop('disabled', this.checked) : 
});
```

Also because the controls have `runa=server` attributes, make sure you use the attribute contains selector.

And don not forget to include the code inside `DOM` ready handler.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best to use event delegation here.

```
$(document).on('change', '[id^="rb"]', function() {
    var txt = $("#txt" + event.target.id.split(/rb/)[1]);

    txt.prop('disabled', this.checked) : 
});
```

Anytime any of the radio buttons change, the corresponding input box will be found and disabled.